# How to capture Oracle SP INOUT parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have Oracle linked server in my SQL Server. I created procedure which executes a stored procedure in Oracle:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ModifySth (
    @var1 nvarchar(255),
    @var2 nvarchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @var3 as NVARCHAR(255);
    EXEC('begin oracleSPname(?, ?, ? ); end;',
            @var1 output,        
            @var2,
            @var3 output,
        )
    at ORACLE
    SELECT @var1 as var1, @Vvar3 as var3;
END
```

When I execute `ModifySth` I am passing two parameters and excepting two output vars. `var1` is `IN OUT`. How to capture `var1`? When I am trying to capture is, I get value which I passed to the stored procedure, not the output value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use an extra variable?

```
DECLARE @var1_reply as NVARCHAR(255);

EXEC('begin oracleSPname(?, ?, ?, ? ); end;',
        @var1,        
        @var1_reply output,
        @var2,
        @var3 output,
    )
at ORACLE

set @var1= @var1_reply;
```